# Maximum value of a column in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to find the maximum value of a column ratingTime using pig.I am running below script :

```
    ratings = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/u.data' AS (userid:int,movieID:int,rating:int, ratingTime:int);
    maxrating = MAX(ratings.ratingTime);
    DUMP maxrating
```

Sample Input data is :

```
    196 242 3   881250949
    186 302 3   891717742
    22  377 1   878887116
    244 51  2   880606923
```

I am getting below error :

```
     2018-08-05 07:02:05,247 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.PigATSClient - Created ATS Hook 

     2018-08-05 07:02:05,914 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file script.pi
```

Comment: How are you running this? You're missing a semicolon on DUMP command

Comment: I tried with semicolon as well, its still not working

Comment: Again, how are you running this? `pig -f` or typing each line in the grunt shell? Can you please edit your post to include a sample of the input file?

Comment: I am running this pig script using ambari web console, also edited question to provide sample input.

Comment: I think you need to load the file `USING PigStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a preceding `GROUP ALL` before applying `MAX`.[Source](https://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/func.html#max)

```
ratings = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/u.data' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (userid:int,movieID:int,rating:int, ratingTime:int);
rating_group = GROUP ratings  ALL;
maxrating = FOREACH ratings_group GENERATE MAX(ratings.ratingTime);
DUMP maxrating;
```